# Drop shadows that cast lines from object

Tags: adobe-illustrator, drop-shadow

Does anyone know of a quick way to create drop shadows that cast lighter from inside corners and heavier from protrusions?

[image]

[**Link**](http://www.shutterstock.com/pic-111558059/stock-vector-eps-vector-cloud-illustration.html?src=t71IgGuCWjyWIhr3DR_8TA-1-10)

Comment: The picture is of adobe illustrator, photoshop tag irrelevant

Answer (score 2):

It is very simple effect created by using Gradient tool applied to a square shape.
Shutterstock does not accept Drop-Shadowed Vectors, thus you can be 100% it is not Drop Shadow tool, but Gradient tool.

This one I've created in 30 seconds -

[image]

If you want exactly the same view - as you asked Smooth one - you should use **Blend tool** as well - the proped tutorial I saw in Vectorboom site (has no link, but you can find it easily yourself)

Also, you can play with a gradient applying it to ellipse with different grey stops...

I've find for you the [tutorial](http://abduzeedo.com/super-easy-soft-shadows-illustrator) you can use for inspiration.

Comment: Hoping there was some filter/setting combo. Thanks.

Comment: @hacklikecrack please, check the tutorial I've provided after editing the answer